# How can I populate a new array with strings passed as command line arguments in argv[]?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, command-line-arguments, argv

I am relatively new to coding, especially in C. I am attempting to create a simple program designed to take a phrase, or list of strings, as command line arguments that populate char* argv[]. I then want to perform simple ASCII based changes to each character (such as making a => b, b => c, ... z => a etc.), and then populate a new array with the altered strings. Essentially, the new object would be an array of arrays of characters, just like I believe argv[] to be.

Here is my code, although I have been bombarded with a variety of "pointer incompatible conversion assignment **char to string int char variable.....Segmentation fault" style errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  


int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    
    char* cipher[argc];  
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)  
    {  
        int n = strlen(argv[i]);  
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)  
        {  
            cipher[i][j] = argv[i][j];  
        }  
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i<argc-1; i++)  
    {  
        printf("%s\n", cipher[i]);  
    }  
}
```

The code would be run via command line as follows:

```
./secret the man in the middle is guilty
```

And then return a scrambled form of this. I have omitted the scrambling algorithm because this was not something I was having issues with.

I understand that I could more easily create code that prints the altered message, but I want to be able to store the new message in an array in case of further alterations. I'm not understanding why I can't just access the values of characters of specific 2d indexes and populate the new "cipher" array with them.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: each string is on its own an array of `char`s. Notice that you have two nested loops but you only allocate one dimension for `cipher`.

Comment: Use `cipher[i] = malloc(n+1)` to allocate memory for the string in `cipher`. And don't forget to add the null terminator.

Comment: @littleadv how can I define a two dimensional array? Is there syntax like a[][] or something else?

Comment: See the comment from Barmar. You defined an array of pointers, which is correct. Now each of them needs to point somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  


int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    

    // first issue: this is only allocating space for "pointers" to
    // strings [argc many] but no space for actual strings so you have to 
    // allocate them.


    // also this is only really workable with c99 (assuming that's the case)
    char* cipher[argc];  

    // this is okay 
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)  
    {  

       // this is where you would allocate space and 
       // perform the copy
        int n = strlen(argv[i]);  
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)  
        {  
            cipher[i][j] = argv[i][j];  
        }  
    }

   
    for (int i = 0; i<argc-1; i++)  
    {  
        printf("%s\n", cipher[i]);  
    }  
}
```

So at least minimally:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
   
    char* cipher[argc];

    // this is okay 
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)  
    {  
         // strdup will return a newly allocated copy
         // and since cipher[] is an array of pointers 
         // you are good to go.
         cipher[i-1] = strdup(argv[i]);
    }

   
    for (int i = 0; i<argc-1; i++)  
    {  
        printf("%s\n", cipher[i]);  
    }  

    // later on after you are finished with cipher 
    // assuming that you still have other things to do
    // you can de-allocate the memory (although not sure if
    // that will be required)

    for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
         free(cipher[i]); // strdup allocated memory cleanup
    }

    // you can no longer use cipher[i] here because it's contents
    // have been destroyed by the free above.
}
```

Comment: Note that [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) is not (yet) part of the ISO C standard.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I think it was added in 2019

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup seems to be saying that.

Comment: Thank you so much! All of my experience in coding is either in Python or in my AP Comp Sci course where the nitty gritty issues like memory allocation aren't really addressed.

Comment: No worries, C takes a lot of practice, I've been programming for 30+ years in it and hehe as @AndreasWenzel pointed out i ended up quoting a function that would've given you a bit of a headache on a lot of non POSIX systems ... My brain C is littered with old standards ;') but ... `strdup` is perfectly good to use on most Unix / Linux systems

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I used char *strdup(const char *s);  as a prototype it wasn't working when I didn't.

Comment: @AhmedMasud The biggest thing for me starting out is understanding that C seems to sacrifice ease of use for insane speed. Do you have any recommendations for getting to understand memory allocation and how to manipulate it in my code or does it just come with hours trying and reading stackoverflow :)

Comment: @AhmedMasud: According to the page I linked to, `strdup` will probably be part of the upcoming ISO C standard, which will probably be voted upon in 2023. Therefore, this standard will probably inofficially be called ISO C23. The function has already been incorporated into [the draft standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2731.pdf).

Comment: @BigFacts the main thing to remember in C is that you get COMPLETE control over everything. This ranges from how much memory, where in memory, also how stuff is layed out in memory and that's just memory :-) ... It comes with practice and still everyone (even the most experienced programmers) make mistakes. Don't be discouraged by that.   Also, there are usually off-by-one errors. And understanding C primitives (e.g. in C there isn't really such a thing a String but rather it is an array of characters terminated by '\0' as the last entry in the array)

Comment: @BigFacts so you essentially have to read a lot and also practice a lot.  :-) Welcome to the wonderful world of C.  Now if you are looking for fast and also memory safe and as low level as C .. .You may want to consider Rust ;) I have switched to it as my main professional language and if you have python background I'd say have a serious look at it.